# Calculate force imparted by falling object on tensioned rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I use ridgelines when hammocking and have various ridgeline cordage with varying breaking strengths. I'm trying to find a basic general formula for calculating how well a particular cord might avoid breaking given a falling object's mass and starting height. For the purpose of this exercise I think we can ignore the lashing knots that suspend the ridgeline and also assume there are no kinks, damage and inline knots on the ridgeline either.

An example is: A cordage with breaking strength of $250\,\text{lbs}$ is rated at $1.13\,\text{kN}$ (unsure where this $1\,\text{lbf} = 4.45\,\text N$ comes from).

Say a $10\,\text{kg}$ object (maybe a branch) falls $10\,\text m$ onto the ridgeline, I calculate the energy of the object to be $$10\,\text{kg}\cdot9.8\,\text m/\text s^2 \cdot 10\,\text m = 980\,\text N$$

Without further consideration, since $980\,\text N < 1130\,\text N$, the ridgeline should not break. However I read that you also need to divide by distance traveled during impact. I suppose this relates to how much the cordage stretches. Since this cord doesn't stretch very much, let's assume given the ridgeline length that the total distance moved during impact is $20\,\text{cm}$ or $0.02\,\text m$. Then it follows that $980\,\text N/0.02\,\text m = 49000$? This is where I'm stuck because $49000$ (not sure what units this is) seems quite large.

Comment: Knots impact the rope.  Also, you need to specify the angles that the ridge line attachments make where they are anchored, the amount of stretch in the ridge line before it breaks, any loads that are on the ridge line before something falls on it, the distance fallen and mass of the falling object, etc.  This problem is solvable in principle, but a lot more data are needed before an answer can be calculated.

Comment: I agree these details are important and I was trying to reduce the problem to get a general sense of even magnitude. Assume bowline knots are used which have a rating of 60%. Ridgeline is tied parallel to the ground to strong posts that are 90deg to the ground (straight up). No additional load on the ridgeline other than the ridgeline weight itself which we can consider to be negligible.

Comment: Is this a bungee cord type of situation or is the tensioned rope horizontal (catenary really) and the object is falling on it?

Comment: @vgar3s, the forces in a horizontal rope are GREATLY magnified relative to a vertical load that is put on it.  The more slack there is in the rope, the bigger the angle the anchor points make with the horizontal, and the lower the forces on the rope.  That angle is absolutely critical when it comes to answering your question.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @jonas thanks. The rope is not bungee-like, it is actually dyneema braid and has very little to not stretch. David: The cord is 250lb breaking strength with little to no stretch. One side is a bowline and the other is a trucker's hitch for 2:1 mechanical advantage and the rope is tensioned to say 40 N. For simplicity sake let's assume each knot's strength is 60%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this question is asking for a general formula to determine whether a cord will break because of a falling object. You've given a breaking force, $1.13\,\text{kN}$ or $1130\,\text N$, and you've given the object's mass, $10\,\text{kg}$, and falling height, $10\,\text m$.
The issue is that we also need to know the stopping distance. The impact force on concrete will be much greater than the impact force on a trampoline. This is because work is equal to force times the distance that force is exerted over, and the work done on the object by gravity is equal to $$mgh=Wh$$ where $m$ is the object's mass, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity, and $h$ is the height it falls from. $W$ is the object's weight. In order to stop the branch, the rope will need to do the same amount of work on the object.

The work done on the object by gravity is equal to $$10\,\text{kg} \cdot 9.8 \,\text m/\text s^2 \cdot 10\,\text m = 980\,\text J$$

In order to do the same amount of work on the object without breaking, the stopping distance must at least by $980\,\text J / 1130\,\text N = 0.87\,\text m$.

Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: Thanks your answer, this makes it quite clear!

Comment: You should keep in mind that this is an idealized scenario, where the force exerted by the rope is independent of how much the rope is stretched, and I'm imagining the rope as if it were hanging straight down with the 10kg object attached at the end like a bungee. If either of those things is not true, it gets more complicated. If you'd like, I can get into more detail.

Comment: If a rope is tight and horizontal between two fixed end points, the tension goes up rapidly with any vertical displacement of the mid-point.

Comment: I'm afraid that this answer is inaccurate in hindsight. It looks like you're asking about a hammock setup instead of a bungee setup. In that case, I'd need to know a lot more before I could give you an answer, like the distance between the ends of the hammock, the length of the hammock, and the elastic coefficient of the rope.